Subgroup of $S_{2024}$ with an $n$-cycle is not simple.
Quetion: Let $G$ be a subgroup of the permutation group $S_{2024}$. And $G$ has an $n$-cycle ($n\geq4$ and $n$ is even.). Prove that $G$ is not a simple group.
My Attempts: To show that $G$ is not simple, I have to construct a nontrivial normal subgroup $H$ of $G$. The $n$-cycle $\tau$ in $G$ forms a cyclic group $\langle\tau\rangle$ which is not a simple group. So $G$ must have other element $\sigma$, and maybe I could show that the subgroup $\langle\sigma,\tau\rangle$ is a normal subgroup... I am stuck in this step. May anyone give me some hints about this question? All help is greatly appreciated!

The use of the number $2024$ suggests the possibility this is a problem in a current contest.  What is the problem's source?  Provide that information and I'll be happy to provide an answer.

even permutations in $G$ form a non trivial normal subgroup

@RobertShore I am a beginner of abstract algebra, and it is my homework... I just wanna some hints to help me solve the question.

Note that when $n$ is even, an $n$-cycle $\sigma$ is an odd permutation, but $\sigma^2$ is an even permutation.

@RobertShore That's right. For any other $\tau$ in $G$, $\tau^{-1}\sigma^{2}\tau$ is still an even permutation, which means it is a nontrivial subgroup of $G$. I have had ideas for this question. Thanks for your help!

The lecturer won't be using this problem next year, for sure.

Let $G$ be a subgroup of $S_n$ containing an odd permutation. It can be shown that half of the permutations in $G$ are odd and other half are even. See this for proof.
Thus, the even permutations in $G$ form a subgroup of $G$ which is of index $2$ and hence, normal in $G$.
In your case, $G$ contains a cycle of even length which is an odd permutation.

$G$ contains a cycle $\sigma$ of even length, which is therefore an odd permutation.  On the other hand, since $\sigma$ is not a $2$-cycle, $\sigma^2 \neq 1$ is an even permutation.  Therefore, $G \cap A_{2024}$ is a non-trivial subgroup of $G$, because $\sigma \notin G \cap A_{2024}$ but $1 \neq \sigma^2 \in G \cap A_{2024}$.  Since $A_{2024} \lhd S_{2024}$, it's easy to see that $G \cap A_{2024} \lhd G$, so $G$ is not simple.
